# Why this model isn't giving appropriate results?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

```
import spacy

# Load the spacy model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Define a function to extract entities and relations from text
def extract_entities_and_relations(text):

  # Create a spacy document from the text
  doc = nlp(text)

  # Get all the entities in the document
  entities = []
  for ent in doc.ents:
    entities.append((ent.text, ent.label_))

  # Get all the relations between entities in the document
  relations = []
  for token in doc:
    if token.dep_ in ["ROOT", "rel"]:
      relations.append((token.head.text, token.text, token.ent_type_))

  # Return a list of rdf triplets
  return [(subject, predicate, object) for subject, predicate, object in relations]

# Test the function
text = "John Doe works at Google. Mumbai is capital of Maharashtra. Bengaluru is in Karnataka. Narendra Modi is prime minister of India."
# print(text)
entities_and_relations = extract_entities_and_relations(text)

# Print the rdf triplets
# print(len(entities_and_relations))
for triplet in entities_and_relations:
  print(triplet)
```

I have to create entity relation extraction model.

above code is giving the output:

```
('works', 'works', '')
('is', 'is', '')
('is', 'is', '')
('is', 'is', '')
```

Comment: The entities list is never used, why?